Deriving tokens from a randomness beacon so that one person gets them first
Is there a way to use a public randomness beacon to generate tokens periodically (say one per week) in such a way that Alice (the silent holder of some secret key) can get the tokens before Bob (a member of the public who merely knows the protocol and can see the beacon)?
Ideally, "before" means Bob needs more random beacon data in order to generate each token, but this seems impossible (since the token is derived by Alice before this data exists), so maybe instead, the delay comes from Bob having a more difficult computational task than Alice.
For example, Alice could obtain the token by performing a "decrypt" operation on the random data, using an encryption scheme weak enough that Bob can do the same decryption (but not discover her key) with more work. I don't know if there is such a scheme.
Another idea: something like LCS35 but with a "salt" parameter so that each random beacon message defines a new time-lock challenge.
Another idea (now that I've read some more): the "protocol" consists of hundreds of years' worth of tokens (or OTPs to be combined with beacon data), each timelock encrypted for the desired time. Is there a better solution using TLE?

It's a good question but technically moot as there is no such thing as a  ‘randomness beacon’.
Yes, there might be a few seemingly independent/temporary entropy sources, but they’re all under control of state agencies like NSA, DGSE or ASIS. E.g. All US cryptographic matters fall under the purview of the NSA. See Federal Information Security Modernization Act (FISMA) of 2014, 44 U.S.C. § 3551. It’s printed on the front of the documents you read.  And Trump has already shut down NIST previously, effectually destroying it’s reputation. DOGE might see it completely disbanded whilst draining.
Since cryptography is a munition and vital for national security, it’s control cannot be divorced from politics.  And politicians say no. Sorry.

Yeah, as I was looking into this yesterday it occurred to me that even the league of entropy (on which drand's time-lock encryption depends) seems somewhat vulnerable to manipulation. Maybe another possible randomness source is the Bitcoin blockchain. Anyway, let's consider my question purely theoretical.

@Karl  I understand, but the problem with theoretical blue sky thinking is that there are no boundaries to the (sane) imagination.  That's a problem as we could just assume the discrete log problem is solved by Alexa AI, we all  start believing in one time pads and your government provides reliable /high quality entropy tokens for your benefit.
